# How to arping a LAN endpoint from within a Docker container running on Windows?

Tags: windows, docker

I'm running Windows 10 with WSL2 and have Docker installed. I create a Docker container and from within that container can ping and ssh into hosts on the same physical LAN as the Windows host, however arping just falls flat on its face.

Example of starting a container from a command prompt on Windows:

```
user@HOST C:\Users\user>wsl --list --verbose
* Ubuntu                 Running         2
  docker-desktop         Running         2
  docker-desktop-data    Running         2
user@HOST C:\Users\user>bash
user@host:~$ sudo docker run -it --rm alpine:3.12.0
/ # ping -c1 -w1 192.168.32.21
PING 192.168.32.21 (192.168.32.21): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.32.21: seq=0 ttl=37 time=1.588 ms

--- 192.168.32.21 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 1.588/1.588/1.588 ms
/ # arping -c1 -w1 192.168.32.21
ARPING 192.168.32.21 from 172.17.0.4 eth0
Sent 1 probe(s) (0 broadcast(s))
Received 0 response(s) (0 request(s), 0 broadcast(s))
```

I have attemped running the container with the default network and '--net=host'; same results.

The '-c1 -w1' options in the above example are there for succinctness. Removing them results in the arping timing out.

Any suggestions/advice would be appreciated. I really need to get the arping working from within the container.

Answer (score 2):

So usually ARP only works on the local LAN segment that the client is connected to, it won't traverse any packet routers.

Looking at the output you've got there, you're trying to go from 172.17.0.4 to 192.168.32.21 which will be on different subnets, so ARP won't work.

Comment: Right. Are there any workarounds for Docker on Windows that would allow it to operate on 192.168.32.0/24? On Linux, for example, passing '--net=host' would allow arping to work from within the container as it has access to host interfaces. WSL2 doesn't expose the host interfaces and creates a WSL adapter that is used by the container.

Comment: I don't *think* you can do that with Docker for Windows, my recommendation would be that if you need a docker container on the same LAN as your network, use Hyper-V to setup a Linux VM bridged to the main network and then run Docker engine on that, and use `--net=host` on the container, so it comes up on the host network.

Comment: Well, that's unfortunate news. Guess I'll have to deploy the arping container on a Linux host and add in some glue to transport results to containers on the Windows side. Thanks for the responses